# How to make JPA use a single join to get columns with conditions for both sides

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

My problem is the following,

There are two entity classes, let's call them `Entity1` and `Entity2` with One-to-Many relationship in between, i.e. one `Entity1` contains multiple `Entity2`s, and `Entity2` may have only one `Entity1`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class Entity1 {

    int x;
    int y;
    ...
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Entity2> entity2s = new HashSet<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
public class Entity2 {

    int a;
    int b;  
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Entity1 e1;

}
```

Now I would like to issue a query for retrieving `Entity2`s with WHERE conditions for both `Entity2` and its corresponding `Entity1`:

```
@Query("SELECT " +
       " e2 " +
       "FROM " +
       " Entity2 e2 " +
       "WHERE " +
       " e2.a = '<val1>' AND e2.b = '<val2>' AND e2.e1.x = '<val3>' AND e2.e1.y ='<val4>'")
List<Entity2> findMyEntity2s(
        @Param...,
        @Param...,
);
```

So the problem with this approach is that, it indeed gets desired `Entity2`s by cross joining `entity1` and `entity2` tables with specified WHERE conditions BUT it fetches `e1`s for each of those `Entity2`s in the result with a separate query.
So for example if the result of join is 5 `Entity2`s, there will be 5 additional queries to `entity1` table.

I tried to set `@ManyToOne` in `Entity2` as `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` but it didn't help. I guess that's expected because `LAZY` would simply postpone the retrieval of `e1`s but wouldn't eliminate it completely.

Next, I read about `@EntityGraph`, and added it to `Entity2`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.entity2.entity1",
    attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("e1") })
public class Entity2 {

    int a;
    int b;  
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Entity1 e1;

}
```

and in the repository, I added it as:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "graph.entity2.entity1")
@Query("SELECT " +
       " e2 " +
       "FROM " +
       " Entity2 e2 " +
       "WHERE " +
       " e2.a = '<val1>' AND e2.b = '<val2>' AND e2.e1.x = '<val3>' AND e2.e1.y ='<val4>'")
List<Entity2> findMyEntity2s(
        @Param...,
        @Param...,
);
```

In this case, the separate SQL queries disappear, EntityGraph does left join and its result contains columns from both `entity1` and `entity2`, BUT because the conditions for `e2.e1` are still in WHERE clause, it adds ONE MORE unnecessary cross join with `entity1` table (`e2.e1` conditions are checked in that cross join).

I couldn't find a way to get rid of that extra cross join, so now I'm using the following query:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "graph.entity2.entity1")
@Query("SELECT " +
       " e2 " +
       "FROM " +
       " Entity2 e2 " +
       "WHERE " +
       " e2.a = '<val1>' AND e2.b = '<val2>'")
List<Entity2> findMyEntity2s(
        @Param...,
        @Param...,
);
```

So basically I get `Entity2`s and in the application I filter out based on conditions of `Entity1` (`e2.e1.x = '<val3>' AND e2.e1.y ='<val4>'`).

Is there a way to make it work with a single join only, for both entity's conditions, not only `Entity2` conditions? The way I'm doing it now, does not seem correct and efficient to me, and I feel there's a way to do that using repository method only, without involving the app. Would appreciate any help on this

UPD. Read about `nativeQuery` option (`nativeQuery = true`) for `@Query` annotation, which allows specifying a raw query and thus bypassing entity-based query, but the query still fetches many-to-one `e1` field, using `entity1_id` (entity graph was disabled). I tried to enable entity graph but it dropped exception stating that entity graph cannot be used with native query, which is expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic n + 1 query problem.
You can read the detail here: https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/

In your query, append:

```
LEFT JOIN FETCH e2.e1 e2e1
```

This will fetch e1 with e2 in the first and single query.

Don't forget; always use FetchType.LAZY and fetch your entities with `JOIN FETCH`. Otherwise, you will get into a big mass while the scope of the project enlarges.

In addition, why do you use Jaxson annotations in your Entity classes? Use entities for only DAO access and map them to another DTOs to use elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, that was it, I don't even need entitygraph now